# Zoom Feature Like Preview Mac App for NSView

Tags: macos, zooming, nsview

I have a NSView. There is a Table inside that View. Now, i want to implement zoom in/out feature like in Preview Mac app.

When user zooms in the scroll should be visible for scroll up and down.

I have already tried with

```
 scaleUnitSquareToSize
```

but no luck so far.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details what you tried?
I expect you have the view which is implement the zoom feature within an NSScrollView correct?